# Product image is not loading in product discription page in Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, product-page

I am facing some problem here the images in the product description is not loading at all. But it is loading well in the category page.

[site link](https://www.b-organized.com.au/)

Please hint that what I can do to solve this problem, I checked some article nothing helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can check your image in product page also

Comment: check link,https://www.b-organized.com.au/kids-toy-storage-box-white.html

Comment: @rakesh did you checked in both browser / private window ?

Comment: Check the output in the console of the browser dev tools. You are getting some JS errors.

Comment: @manikantagowda check my answer will help you!

Comment: Yes Its working fine for Incognito mode also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your site view source page and found unproper jQuery added.

```
<script type="45d1a9876451f4c400ef0c91-">
$(document).ready(
        function() {
   var  mn = $(".page-header");
   var mns = "main-nav-scrolled";

$(window).scroll(function() {
 if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
   mn.addClass(mns);
 } else {
   mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
}); 
});
</script>
```

Add your jquery code inside:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    //your jquery code//
 });
```

Please update your code as per suggestion and check again.

Run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: i am checking by removing that code from header .

Comment: @manikantagowda then flush the cache and deploy again.

Comment: sure , but i am not getting now where this code is coming from ! i mean from which file

Comment: @manikantagowda  you can remove it from:  Admin > Content > Theme > select your theme > HTML Head > Scripts and Style Sheets

Comment: i have removed the code and i have done "flush cache storage" and "flush magneto cache" and also done "index resubmission" but still that code is appearing in header ! i don't know how

Comment: @manikantagowda use both one by one 1) rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ 
2) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: sorry to say this , i don't have SSH access connect root folder , any i do it using FTP ot in backend ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78418/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-manikanta-gowda).

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3398699/c28008913ba65712bc230694ed541164

Comment: Welcome... Happy to help!